# Magento bin/magento parse error with Wamp

Tags: php, command-line, magento2

I'm new to MAgento and I have some trouble executing the magento command.

When I'm using

```
C:/my-project-root/bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I have the following error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'try' (T_TRY) in C:\my-project-root\bin\magento on line 13
```

I'm with Wampserver, PHP version 5.6.31, but I run this command from the PHP7.0.23 directory because of Magento requisitie.

I've take a look at the forum to solve it, but there is no way...

When I change my PHP folder in the PATH to PHP7.0.23 the result is the same..

Anyone has an idea ?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I personnaly do is actually specify what php executable file I use with its relevant config (ini file).

> go to your magento folder

```
cd C:\my-project-root\www\ ;
```

> use the php 7 executable, with its relevant ini config file.
>
> **WARNING**, the below example should be adapted with YOUR correct file paths

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php-7.0.4-Win32-VC14-x86\php.exe -c "C:\wamp\bin\php\php-7.0.4-Win32-VC14-x86\php.ini" C:\my-project-root\bin\magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
When I do this, I have a result like that :
`PADPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGX
XPADDINGPADD └  ↑   ░º©º╚ºÓºÞºP®X®   ð  ¿   ↑®H®h®x®ê®ÿ®¿®©®╚®Ï®Þ®¬↑¬(¬8¬H¬X¬h¬x¬ê¬ÿ¬¿¬©¬╚¬Ï¬`

Comment: And that
`<!-- Windows Vista -->
    <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"></supportedOS>
           <!-- Windows 7 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"></supportedOS>
           <!-- Windows 8 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"></supportedOS>
           <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"></supportedOS>
           <!-- Windows 10 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"></supportedOS>
       </application>`

Comment: Answer updated. Changed slashes to backslash and removed an extra char ( ' ). It might solve the above.